# Serving static images in the development environment

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-media

I'm getting this broken image when I try to serve it from the media root. Kindly requesting you..not to show me the links for the docs or to previous questions. I've tried those things but I'm still getting this broken image.

Models.py:

```
class BasicModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.DateField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='sample')

class BasicModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = BasicModel
```

Views.py:

```
def BasicView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BasicModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    data = form.save()
                    return preview(request, data.id)
    else:
            form = BasicModelForm()
    return render_to_response("unnamed.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def preview(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BasicModel, pk=id)
    return render_to_response("preview.html", {'obj': obj})
```

Settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/nirmal/try/files/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/files/'
```

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^unnamed/$', 'unnamed.views.BasicView'),
url(r'^files/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Preview.html:

```
<html>
<body>
{{ obj.name }}
{{ obj.dob }}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}sample/{{ obj.photo }}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
{{ MEDIA_URL }}sample/{{ obj.photo }}
```

With:

```
{{ object.photo.url }}
```

As a side note, are you sure that {{ MEDIA_URL }} is even defined in the template ?

Comment: Why the first syntax is wrong? Both gives the same url  http://localhost:8000/files/sample/qlimp.jpg

Comment: This is a job for ipdb. Run pip install ipdb. Then in your view put "import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()". There, you can enter "form.instance.photo.url" or "from django.conf.settings import MEDIA_URL; MEDIA_URL + form.instance.photo", and compare the results.  A comment is to short to elaborate but you can read my article about debugging: http://blog.yourlabs.org/debugging-python-and-django-code

Answer (score 1):

I think to remember that the ImageField representation returns the URL relative to `MEDIA_URL`. Which means you should use the following code in your template:

```
<html>
<body>
{{ obj.name }}
{{ obj.dob }}
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ obj.photo }}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Or even shorter, use the absolute URL path with:

```
<html>
<body>
{{ obj.name }}
{{ obj.dob }}
<img src="{{ obj.photo.url }}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hint, look up the URL of the broken image in your browser. I guess it is something like `http://localhost:8000/files/sample/sample/xyz.png`.